# Custom color for Reporting Services KPI

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to add a custom color (in other words, add some custom status and corresponding color) for [Reporting Services KPI's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/working-with-kpis-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017) (outside of standart red, yellow and green). Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your element and go to the properties (pane on the right side) under **Font > Color** for foreground color and **Fill > BackgroundColor** for the background color and type in the hexadecimal color code. For example:

```
#01b8aa
```

You can browse on google how to convert from `RGB()` into hexadecimal codes.

Comment: I'm talking about [this stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/working-with-kpis-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You would have needed some more tags. I will tag this question to fit into the right section.